# TCPDF: PNG image rendered incorrectly

Tags: php, pdf, png, tcpdf

I'm working on a project which involves TCPDF. I've been working with it for a while now but, after the last update (6.0) my PNG images get really broken although its fragments still visible on the document.

I'm using the Image() method as follows:
`$pdf->Image($img, $x, $y, $twidth, $theight);`

where $img is the source URL, $x and $y the position and $twidth and $theight the size.
I've tested GIF and JPG and it works just fine. There is a GIF image on the PDF to prove that. The PNG image is the VLC icon logo.

The image:

[image]

Comment: @do you have the original image? bacause your link is no longer available

Comment: @carla sorry, I've remove it since I found the problem. I no longer have the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [project site](http://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/da4cf78c/#c64c), to a user who had a similar problem:

> Probably you have problems with PNG images with transparency that are
>   handled in different way depending on the php-imagick or php-gd
>   version used. Try to update php-imagick and disable php-gd

Comment: I've tried, still the same. Now running Image Magick 6.7.3 Q16

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, tcpdf not displaying PNG only images.
(provided tbe path of the images are correct)

It is definetely a GD version problem, at least when you still use old versions of PHP (like 5.3). Uninstalling/removing Gd is often not an option, because it is used elsewhere.

Here is how I fixed it: **the general idea is to force TCPDF to use imagemagick instead of GD for PNG files. Without removing GD.**

Steps:

- Install imagemagick dev packages

  On debian:

  `apt-get -y install libmagickwand5 libmagickwand-dev`
- Install imagemagick PECL extension (via apt or by compiling it->google is your friend)
- don't forget to activate

  `echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20090626-zts/imagick.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/41-imagick.ini`
- in TCPDF somewhere (top of the file?) define a global variable:

  `define('USE_GD',0);`
- in tcpdf.php (my version is tcpdf 5.0.002) within the function `public function Image($file, $x='', $y='', $w=0, $h=0, $type=''....)` near line 5305:

  - find

    `if ( (method_exists($this, $mtd)) AND (!($resize AND function_exists($gdfunction))))`

    replace by (USE_GD added)

    `if (USE_GD && (method_exists($this, $mtd)) AND (!($resize AND function_exists($gdfunction))))`
  - find (a few lines below)

    `if (function_exists($gdfunction)) {`

    replace by (USE_GD added)

    `if (USE_GD && function_exists($gdfunction)) {`
  - and generally speaking everywhere `function_exists($gdfunction)` is mentioned

Comment: I had the direction from here: TCPDF - PHP class for PDF / Discussion / Help:PNG issues on some servers only
https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/da4cf78c/#c64c

Comment: Thanks Ndir, this fixed the issue for me.  I was using an old version (TCPDF 6.0.049) and had to move to a different server where I encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because I had the same problem i pick up this old problem. In my case the solution was simple:

> Open the Image with Photoshop --> Save for web

I know this is not a real solution for the problem, but it could be a simple work-around that saves you a lot of time.